# What is the type of transformation that maps a vector to a line that doesn't go through the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

For simplicity's sake, I'll focus on the xy plane.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{S}$, where $\mathbb{S}$ is the line in $\mathbb{R^2}$ described by $y=2x+1$.

This would be akin to a linear transformation but it's not because im(f)=S is not a subspace. (Doesn't contain <0,0>). What is this kind of mapping called?

Comment: I don't think any reasonable name could be given. All you have is a function mapping the plane into a line. The function could be a constant function (e.g. every point in the plane goes to $(1,3)),$ or it could be very pathological (such as a one-to-one correspondence between the plane and the line).

Comment: I would say an "affine transformation".  That includes a linear transformation that would map to a subspace (line or plane containing the origin) and a trannslation away from the origin.

Comment: @user247327: I initially said "affine" (with a link to [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffineFunction.html)), but then realized that $y = 2x + 1$ is not the function asked about, but rather a description of the co-domain, so I deleted my comment and wrote another one. I *think* maybe the OP is confused, and "affine" is an appropriate answer to what the OP intended to ask, but I decided to post my comment on what actually seems to be asked in the hopes of getting a revision when the OP realized what was asked is not what was intended.

Comment: Affine is what I was looking for! Thanks everyone! To be clear I was asking about the transformation f, not the line y = 2x + 1. I'm sorry if that was confusing.